# Calculating normal to line towards given side

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry

Given is a line (segment), defined by two vectors `start(x,y)` and `end(x,y)`. I also have a point `p(x,y)`, which is on either of the two areas separated by the line (i.e. it is **not** exactly on the line).

How can I calculate the normal to the line that is facing towards the side in which `p` is?

Comment: You want the minimum distance of _p_ to the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let:

```
A = (a,b) and B = (c,d) define the line segment
P = (p,q) be the other point.
```

Define:

```
dot( (p,q), (r,s) ) == p*r + q*s
```

Then the vector:

```
v = ( c-a, d-b)
```

defines the direction along the line segment. Its perpendicular is:

```
u = (d-b, (-(c-a)) = (d-b,a-c)
```

This can be seen by taking the dot product with `v`. To get the normal from the perpendicular, just divide by its length:

```
n = u /|u|, |u| = sqrt( dot(u,u))
```

We now just need to know where `P` lies relative to the normal. If we take:

```
dir = dot( (P-A), n) )
```

Then `dir > 0` means `n` is in the same direction as `P`, whilst `dir < 0` means it is in the opposite direction. Should `dir == 0`, then `P` is in fact on the extended line (not necessarily the line segment itself).

Answer (score 1):

First, determine which side of the line the point lies on, by taking the cross product of `end-start` and `p-end`:

z = (x<sub>end</sub>-x<sub>start</sub>)(y<sub>p</sub>-y<sub>end</sub>) - (y<sub>end</sub>-y<sub>start</sub>)(x<sub>p</sub>-x<sub>end</sub>)

If z>0, then the point is to the left of the line (as seen by a person standing at **start** and facing **end**). If z<0, then the point is to the right of the line.

Second, normalize the line segment:

**S** = **end** - **start**
**k** = **S**/|**S**|

Finally, if the point is to the left of the line, rotate **k** to the left:

(x<sub>k</sub>, y<sub>k</sub>) => (-y<sub>k</sub>, x<sub>k</sub>)

or if the point is to the right of the line, rotate **k** to the right:

(x<sub>k</sub>, y<sub>k</sub>) => (y<sub>k</sub>, -x<sub>k</sub>)

Answer (score 0):

My math skills are a bit rusty, so I can't give you the exact calculations, but what you do is this (assuming 2D from your description):

1. First you calculate a normal n.
2. Then you calculate P' which is the perpendicular projection of your point P onto your line.
   Basically, what you do is, you "create" another line and use your vector n from step 1 as the direction (`y = p + x * n` where y,p and n are vectors, p is actually your p(x,y) and x is a real number), then you intersect this line with the first one and the point where they intersect is P'.
   Seeing you're from Austria, everyone else please forgive me for using one German word, I really don't know the English translation and couldn't find any. P' = Lotfußpunkt
3. Calculate P - P'. If it has the same sign as n in both components, n is the normal you're searching for. If it has the opposite sign, -n is the one you're searching for.

I hope the idea is clear even though I don't know all the technical terms in English.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on step 2? Thanks.

Comment: Just updated my answer, hope that makes it clearer. Instead of step 3, you could also solve the equation from step 2 for x and if x is negative, n is your answer, however if x is positive, -n is your answer.

Answer (score 0):

For
start = (a,b)
end = (c,d)
p = (x,y)

Slope(startend) = (d - b) / (c - a)

Slope(norm) = -(c - a) / (d - b)

Norm line must include p = (x,y), so

ynorm = -((c - a) / (d - b)) * xnorm + (y + ((c - a) / (d - b)) * x)

Comment: What is the value of `xnorm` in your last line?

Comment: ynorm and xnorm are variables in the equation for the normal

Answer (score 0):

y =  mx + c

is the normal line equation where m is the slope and c is any constant.

You have start and end. Lets call them (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) and the line joining them L1. 
The slope of this line, m1, is (y2-y1)/(x2-x1). This line is perpendicular to the line you need which we can call L2 with slope m2. The product of slopes of 2 mutuallu perpendicular lines is -1. Hence, 
m1*m2=-1.

Hence you can calculate m2. Now, you need to find the equation of the line L2. You have 1 point in the line P (x,y). You can substitute in this manner: 
y=m2*x+c.

This will give you c. Once you have the line equation, you can convert it to parametric form as shown below:

http://thejuniverse.org/PUBLIC/LinearAlgebra/LOLA/lines/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The equation of the line is given as

```
A = start.y-end.y
B = end.x-start.x
C = start.x*end.y-start.y*end.x

A*x + B*y + C = 0
```

The minimum distance `d` to the line of a point `p=(px,py)` is

```
d = (A*px+B*py+C)/sqrt(A^2+B^2)
```

If the value is positive then the point is at a counter clockwise rotation from the vector `(start->end)`. If negative then it is in clockwise rotation. So if `(start->end)` is pointing up, then a positive distance is to the left of the line.

Example

[image: geo]

```
start = (8.04, -0.18)
end = (6.58, 1.72)
P = (2.82, 0.66)
A = (-0.18)-(1.72) = -1.9
B = (6.58)-(8.04) = -1.46
C = (8.04)*(1.72)-(-0.18)*(6.58) = 15.01
d = (A*(2.82)+B*(0.66)+C)/√(A^2+B^2) = 3.63
```

The calculation for `d` shows the identical value as the length of vector `(near->P)` in the sketch.

Answer (score 0):

`N = (Ey - Sy, Sx - Ex)` is perpendicular to the line (it is `SE` rotated by 90°, not normalized).

Then compute the sign of the dot product

```
N . SP = (Ey - Sy)(Px - Sx) + (Sx - Ex)(Py - Sy),
```

it will tell you on what side the normal is pointing.